# HTTP Status 404 – Not Found while calling url in spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, http, spring-mvc, http-status-code-404

[Service response in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rtliz.jpg)

I am getting HTTP status 404 while calling URL on browser of simple created spring boot app. Below is the code. There is no error or problem in my code. I am just copy past my code from internet.

**Main spring boot app class**

```
   package com.springboot.app;
   
   import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
   import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
   import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
   
   @SpringBootApplication
   public class SampleBootAppApplication {
   
       public static void main(String[] args) {
           SpringApplication.run(SampleBootAppApplication.class, args);
       }
   
   }
```

Below is the controller class

**Controller Class**

```
    package com.springboot.app.controller;
    
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
    
    @RestController
    public class AppController {
    
        
        @GetMapping("/test")
        @ResponseBody
        public String getName()
        {
            return "adil abdullah";
        }
    }
```

**Project structure:**

[Project structure in spring tool suite](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bi6BY.png)

Comment: show your application.properties file. You can delete ResponseBody. It's needed when you are using @Controller annotation

Comment: Have you put any context path in your application.properties?

Answer (score 1):

Accessing Url is wrong  : http://localhost:8080/test
It should have context path, It will be in application.properties file
like., server.servlet.context.path = /samplebootapp
Access URL : http://localhost:8080/samplebootapp/test

Comment: OP didn't share the properties file yet. Your answer is based on the prediction. Better ask him to share the details and give your response accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

Use this

```
package com.springboot.app.controller;
    
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    
    @Controller
    public class AppController {
    
        
        @GetMapping("/test")
        @ResponseBody
        public String getName(){

            return "adil abdullah";
        }
    }
```

##### And paste this in browser  http:localhost:8080/test

Answer (score -1):

Issue in the Package structure. If you have correct package structure then that main application should available within (`src/main/java`). That's why controller missing from component scan. Follow below ways.

1. delete the controller package and recreate again by right clicking on base package not from `src/main/java`
2. Or else add `@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.springboot.app")`

Comment: Page not found mean your application running bit could find the URL. I am sure your your controller bean not initialized if not provide full code. We can assume whatever you provide.